# Convert Decimal to Binary (Bitmap of a character)

Tags: objective-c, ios, bitmap

I have a question about getting a Bitmap from a character, for example A.

I was already searching in the internet but no direct help. I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29461/Led-Font-Creator-with-Scrolling-Display) page, where my plans are described.

Quotation from this site:

e.g. character char="A" bits="227873781661662" which translates to “0000 0000 0000 0000 1100 1111 0011 1111 1111 1111 1100 1111 0011 1111 1101 1110” in binary.

How do they get from 227873781661662 to 0000 0000 0000 0000 1100 1111 0011 1111 1111 1111 1100 1111 0011 1111 1101 1110?

```
int num = 227873781661662;
int n = log(num)/log(2)+1;          //Figure out the maximum power of 2 needed
NSString *result = @"";             //Empty string
for (int j=n; j>=0; j--)            //Iterate down through the powers of 2
{
    if (pow(2,j) >= num)            //If the number is greater than current power of 2
    {
        num -= pow(2,j);                             //Subtract the power of 2
        result = [result stringByAppendingString:@"1"]; //Add a 1 to result string
    }
    else result = [result stringByAppendingString:@"0"]; //Otherwise add a 0

    if (num == 0) break;                              //If we're at 0, stop
}
NSLog(@"num = %i",num);
```

What is wrong with this? Thanks for help

Comment: they converted the number **form decimal** system **to binary** system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a number from decimal to binary:

```
long long num = 938409238409283409;
int n = log(num)/log(2)+1;          //Figure out the maximum power of 2 needed
NSString *result = @"";             //Start with empty string
for (int j=n; j>=0; j--)            //Iterate down through the powers of 2
{
    long long curPOW = powl(2,j);
    if (curPOW <= num)          //If the number is greater than current power of 2
    {
        num -= curPOW;                                  //Subtract the power of 2
        result = [result stringByAppendingString:@"1"]; //Add a 1 to result string
    }
    else result = [result stringByAppendingString:@"0"]; //Otherwise add a 0
}
NSLog(@"%@", result); //Result is now binary representation of num
```

With the example `num` above output is:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. For the value 227873781661662 in my question I get -3194914 for num. What can be wrong? Thanks

Comment: I had 1 and 0 as numbers, instead of strings. Putting them in the format @"1" and @"0" should fix it.

Comment: You know the num isn't the result, right? The result is the string named `result`. Also your number is greater than the maximum allowed int value; you should use long long or something like that.

Comment: Yeah..now I know. I changed the num into a long but the result is nil, when I log it out. Can you please check that behavior?

Comment: I just checked this code; it works fine on my machine and allows the text of a textfield to be set to the result string's value.

Comment: that's crazy...But thank you for the moment. I will try a bit and hope to get it working :)

Comment: By "this code" I mean the code I just added 4 minutes ago. The problem was that I was using `pow` instead of `powl` and an `int` intead of a `long long` to store the number to subtract.

Comment: Now it's working..I took your new Code. Thank you very much for the help. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 3):

They show you a decimal representation of a 64-bit binary number. Their code interprets the number as an upside-down `8x6` matrix of bits, with the initial 16-bit portion thrown away.

The bits are re-grouped below to illustrate what is going on. I groped by bits by six, and put an asterisk for `1` and a space for `0` to produce an image below:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 -- Thrown away
bits    image
------  ------
110011  **  **      
110011  **  **
111111  ******
111111  ******
110011  **  **
110011  **  **
111111  ******
011110   ****
```

On windows you can use the calculator application to convert binary to decimal and back. Choose [View/Programmer], and then select "Bin" radio button.

Here is how you can convert a number to binary in Objective C:

```
long long num = 227873781661662L;
NSMutableString *res = [NSMutableString string];
while (res.length != 64) {
    [res insertString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num%2] atIndex:0];
    num >>= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The 227873781661662 is in decimal, obviously the 1's and 0's are binary. To convert decimal into binary either [break the number up into powers of 2](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary) (ie, 2^0=1, 2^1=2, 2^2=4) which would be long for a big number like that, or just use a [calculator tool](http://acc6.its.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~gurwitz/core5/nav2tool.html)